# Reference one string from another string in Localizable.strings

Tags: ios, xcode

I would like to reference a string from another string in my Localizable.strings file, like we do in android's strings.xml file as below

```
<string name="app_name">My App</string>   
<string name="activity_title">@string/app_name</string>
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated. I tried looking for the documentation and also stackoverflow, but couldnt get anything out of it.

Comment: @LuciusHipan that question is for android. Mine is for iOS.

Comment: sorry for that, my fault

Comment: I develop for both platforms, with most of my experience in Android, somethings in iOS title shock me that they don't work better, bring localization is one of them.

Answer (score 4):

iOS **Localizable.strings** is not as flexible as Android's **strings.xml**. You cannot do this from plist, only from code.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a helper class like this:

**Lang.h File**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Lang : NSObject
+(NSString *)getString : (NSString *)key;
@end
```

**Lang.m File**

```
#import "Lang.h"

@implementation Lang

+(NSString *)getString : (NSString *)key
{
    @try {
        NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"en" ofType:@"lproj"];

        NSBundle* languageBundle = [NSBundle bundleWithPath:path];
        //find and return the desired string
        NSString* str = [languageBundle localizedStringForKey:key value:@"" table:nil];
        return str;
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception) {
        return @"";
    }
}

@end
```

Create a .string file and add your key-value to this file as attached image:

[image]

Now you can get the value of your key like this:

```
NSString *value = [Lang getString:@"YOUR_KEY"];
```